# Creating random points based on a classified raster WITHOUT detour via raster-to-vector-conversion (QGIS 3.16, Win10)

Tags: raster, point, software-recommendations, classification, random

I'd like to create a random-point-vector-file from a classified raster with a given number of points per class.

I found several solutions or tool recommendations in diverse forums. But, all these approaches required to convert the raster into a (classified) polygone vector-file in advance. Within half a day I could not find any tool/approach without that detour.

Is there any tool by which it is possible to generate random points **directly** from a classified raster?

Answer (score 1):

Within the EnMAP-Box plugin you'll find a tool that is called *Random points from Classification*.

It's a quite basic tool:

You can specify

- your raster,
- the number of random points per class, and
- the type of vector output.
  That's it.

You can't

- integrate a mask,
- specify differing numbers per class,
- specify the number of search attmpts,
- specify the minimum distance between points or
- any other extras.

This might be enough for one or another task but is not a comprehensive 'random-points-directly-from-raster-tool'.